# How do I install newer python on CentOS with minimal effort?

Tags: centos, redhat, python, mod-python

I would like to install Python 2.6 and mod_python on CentOS 5 (x64).

The system is delivered with old python 2.4 and I want the new one with minimal maintenance effort (compiling and having a different installation seams to be suboptimal solution).

Is there a solution for this, other than starting to recompile lots of packages? If not should I switch to Ubuntu?

Please remember that I'm talking about x64 - I found a repository on net with updated packages but it is not x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an [additional repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) like the one of the [IUS Community Project](http://iuscommunity.org/), which contains the latest release of Python 2.6 and 3.1.

Comment: Thanks this worked. One remark I had to make a symlink between /usr/local/lib/python2.6 and /usr/lib/python2.6 because python did not find the packages installed with easy_install/setuptools.